# Confused with promises

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node js code to get data from azure SQL. Here I'm able to fetch and print it correctly. But the issue is I want to print it in another location. Below is my code.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var tp = require('tedious-promises');

var x = [];
// Create connection to database
var config = {
    userName: 'myUserName',
    password: 'MyPwd',
    server: 'myServer',
    options: {
        database: 'myDB',
        encrypt: true
    }
}
tp.setConnectionConfig(config);

function queryDatabase() {
    console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');
    tp.sql("select TOP 10 title FROM dbo.Table").forEachRow(function(row) {
            x.push(row.title + "====");
        }).execute()
        .then(function(results) {
            console.log(x);   <======= It is printing here correctly.
        }).fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

queryDatabase();
console.log("========");
console.log(x);<============ I want it to print the value here
```

My current output is like below.

```
========
[]
(node:15608) [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is deprecated. Please use tls.Socket instead.
[Here all the values are printed ]
```

But my expected output is

```
(node:15608) [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is deprecated. Please use tls.Socket instead.
[Here all the values are printed ]
========
[Here all the values are printed ]
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: Let `queryDatabase()` return the Promise returned by `tp.sql()` and move the `.then().catch()` block where you want to have the value available.

Comment: console.log(x); line is being executed before you get the result from database and assign it to x. that's why it is printing empty result. use async-await promises. or write your logic where you're console logging the x.

Answer (score 0):

Promise is async, you must use a callback in your function or transform your function into promise :

Callback  version :

```
function queryDatabase(callback) {
    var x = [];
    console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');
    tp.sql("select TOP 10 title FROM dbo.Table").forEachRow(function(row) {
            x.push(row.title + "====");
        }).execute()
        .then(function(results) {
            console.log(x);   <======= It is printing here correctly.
            return callback(null, x);
        }).fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err, null);
        });
}


queryDatabase(function(err, result){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("========");
        console.log(x);<============ I want it to print the value here
    }

});
```

Promise version :

```
function queryDatabase() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var x = [];
        console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');
        tp.sql("select TOP 10 title FROM dbo.Table").forEachRow(function(row) {
            x.push(row.title + "====");
        }).execute()
        .then(function(results) {
            console.log(x);   <======= It is printing here correctly.
            return resolve(x);
        }).fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return reject(err);
        });
    });
}


queryDatabase()
.then(function(result){

      console.log("========");
     console.log(result);<============ I want it to print the value here
})
.catch(function(err){

   console.log(err) 

});
```

Comment: it is already a promise function. why would you even create a promise function on top of it?

Comment: queryDatabase contains a promise, but the function itself isn't a promise. If you want to use this function as a promise when you call it, it must return a promise. Otherwise the .then() and .catch() aren't defined on queryDatabase

Comment: he wants the result outside of the function(not in the callback) which is not possible.

Comment: @VivekAasaithambi, I dunno how. but this code worked for me. Can you please provide a code with better performance